Simplify an infinite sum
Is there a simplified expression for the infinite sum:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n! (n+k-1)!} f_n^{(k+n-1)}(x_0),$$
where $a$ is a constant, $f_n(x)=x^n g(x)$ is a function ($g$ is another function), and the superscript on $f_n$ indicates its derivatives of different orders, evaluated at $x_0$?
What I've thought of so far, is that we can use the Taylor series on the $k-1$ derivative of a function, $f^{(k-1)}(x)$, to write:
$$\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{a^n}{n!} f^{(k+n-1)}(x_0) = f^{(k-1)}(x_0+a),$$
but here $f_n$ changes with $n$, and we have an extra $(n+k-1)!$ factor.
The form also looks similar to the modified Bessel function of the first kind, but without the derivatives of $f$:
$$I_{k-1}(x)=\sum_{n=0}^\infty \frac{(x/2)^{2n+k-1}}{n! (n+k-1)!}$$

Yes that is possible

This should help together with Taylor's theorem.
Let $f(x) = \sum f_n x^n$ and $g(x) = \sum g_n x^n$
Then
$$T(x) = 2 \pi \sum f_n g_n x^n = \int_0^{2 \pi} f(\sqrt x \exp(it))g(\sqrt x \exp(-it)) dt$$

Maybe there is a better way for your specific case, not sure

Are you familiar with hypergeometric functions ? That might be what you want in some cases.

Series multisection might help in some cases too

I suggest you should take an other look.

@Stop Putin : why ? what is wrong ? The extra factor $(n+k-1)!$ is adressed here. Did you downvote ? Do you have a better answer ?

Hi, it's not clear to me how you wrote the equations you wrote, what is T(x), and what any of it has to do with my question.

@AbhranilDas $T(x)$ is defined. Well say for instance $g_n = 1/(n+k-1)!$. So then you have an integral expression for modifying the taylor series by a factor $g_n$.

@mick No, downvote is not that constructive, as I see it.
When it comes to my comment, it is easy to find counterexamples for the identity with the integral. For example: for almost any $f$ (non-constant and integrable, and set $g(x)= 1$. Then $T(x)=2\pi f(x)$, while $$\int_0^{2\pi}f(\sqrt{x}\operatorname{exp}(it))g(\sqrt{x}\operatorname{exp}(-it)),dt = \int_0^{2\pi}f(\sqrt{x}\operatorname{exp}(it)),dt =$$   $$\int_0^{2\pi} \sum f_nx^{n/2}e^{int},dt = $$ $$f_0 +\sum_{n\not=0}f_nx^{n/2} \frac{e^{2in\pi}- 1}{in} =f_0$$

@Stop Putin Im pretty certain my formula is correct, at least for entire functions. I was afraid of a typo, so  tested it with excel and math software too. And by paper. In fact even a generalization holds true. You can check that it is analogue to additive just like taylor series are additive. And you can check that if $f(z)$ is the exponential and $g(z)$ is a 0-1 polynomial then the formula holds. It is very similar to fourier. And proving it is not so hard.

@Stop Putin notice you forgot to use $g_n$ for instance. Your computation is an error.
